# Optimizing code that needs to run through a lot of different numbers for Project Euler

Tags: c, programming-challenge

I have been working on Project Euler [problem number 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12). I have code that will get me the right answer, however it takes too long. I know the code works because I have tested it multiple times with numbers that are smaller and take much less time to iterate through. I first wrote essentially the same thing in python, but I know C is faster so I gave it a shot in C, but my solution is just not efficient. Here is the code (in C):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int num = 0;
  int i;
  int j;
  int divisors = 0;
  for (i=1; i<10000; i++){
    num += i;

    for (j=1; j<=num; j++) {
      if (num % j == 0) {
        divisors += 1;
      }
    }

    if (divisors > 500) {
      printf("Num is %d\n", num);
      printf("Divs are %d\n", divisors);
    }

    divisors = 0;

  }
}
```

Project Euler problems are supposed to be solved in under a minute of run-time anyways, so this isn't a great solution even if I let it run until I got an answer.

**Any suggestions on ways to do this faster would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!  This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question (not behind a link). The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231).

Comment: Please add the text of the Project Euler problem to the question before the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Iterating [1...num] is too slow**
**Only [1...sqrt(num)] needed**

Instead of

```
for (j=1; j<=num; j++) {
  if (num % j == 0) {
    divisors += 1;
  }
}
```

Go to the root of `num` (when `j*j <= num`) and get 2 or 1 divisors.

```
for (j=1; j*j <= num; j++) {
  if (num % j == 0) {
    divisors += 1;
    if (j*j < num) divisors += 1;
  }
}
```

Re-formulate to avoid `j*j` overflow

```
for (j=1; j < num/j; j++) {
  if (num % j == 0) {
    divisors += 2;
  }
}
if (j == num/j) {
  divisors += 1;
}
```

Note: Many compilers with recognize the nearby `num/j` and `num % j` and perform the operation for the time cost one of one.

**Example**

Consider `num == 36`.  Original code tries 36 numbers with the starred ones having an exact division.

1*,2*,3*,4*,5,6*,7,8,9*,10,11,12*,13,14,15,16,17,18*,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36*.

Notice that when `num%j == 0`, both `j` and `num/j` are divisors.  Except when `j == num/j`, that discovers two unique divisors at once.  Code only needs to  iterate to 6.

j=1, divisors: 1 & 36
j=2, divisors: 2 & 18
j=3, divisors: 3 & 12
j=4, divisors: 4 & 9
j=5, divisors: none
j=6, divisor: 6

6 iterations faster than 36.

With a `num = 1,000,000`, new code will iterate to 1000 rather than 1,000,000 - a thousand times faster.

---

**Detail on overflow possibility.**

Consider `num` is at or near `INT_MAX`:

With `for (j=1; j<=INT_MAX; j++) {`, `j` will attempt to increment beyond `INT_MAX` resulting in *undefined behavior*.

With `for (j=1; j*j < near_INT_MAX; j++) {`, Unless `near_INT_MAX` is a perfect square, `j*j` will overflow.  Again *undefined behavior*.

With `for (j=1; j < num/j; j++) {`, `j` never overflow for all `num`.

====

There are many more advance techniques for faster code.

Comment: Code works great but could you go back and explain it all a little more? I'm trying to understand why this works so well so I can use things like this in the future.

Comment: @joelanbanks3 OK

Comment: That's super cool! Thank you so much!